Add class to header when some div touch the top of browser
I'm trying to change a class of header when some element touch top of page. If div is background white to add header class black, so text will be visible. This code only works one time even if multi .header-hover is on page. .header-hover add class black, .remove-header remove class black and then next .header-hover do nothing.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $('.header-hover').each(function() {
      var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      if (offset <= 0) {
        $("header").addClass("black");
      }
    })
  });
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $('.remove-header').each(function() {
      var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      if (offset <= 0) {
        $("header").removeClass("black");
      }
    })
  });
});
header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}

header.black {
  background-color: black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hr">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>La Vol</title>


  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style-0e62f56b3f.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qfc8yrb.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.png">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="font-body">

  <header>
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="w-full">
          <a class="header-logo" href="/">
            <img class="hl-1" src="/images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
          </a>
          <a class="header-lang" href="t/en">en</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="home-hero video-cover cursor-hover header-hover">
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-20 xl:-mx-20">
        <div class="w-full xl:px-20">
          <h1 class="leading-none xl:leading-80 mb-30 xl:mb-50 font-title text-4xl xl:text-7xl xxl:text-8xl text-center">
            Some title
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="home-intro py-50 xl:py-100 remove-header">
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-20 xl:-mx-20">
        <div class="w-full xl:px-20">
          <h2 class="leading-none xl:leading-80 mb-30 xl:mb-50 font-title text-4xl xl:text-7xl xxl:text-8xl text-center">
            Some title
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="home-bullets pb-50 xl:pb-100 remove-header">
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-20 xl:-mx-20">
        <div class="w-full xl:px-20">
          <h2 class="leading-none xl:leading-80 mb-30 xl:mb-50 font-title text-4xl xl:text-7xl xxl:text-8xl text-center">
            Some title
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="home-work py-50 xl:py-100 bg-primary cursor-hover header-hover">
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-20 xl:-mx-20">
        <div class="w-full xl:px-20">
          <h2 class="leading-none xl:leading-80 mb-30 xl:mb-50 font-title text-4xl xl:text-7xl xxl:text-8xl text-center">
            Some title
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="home-news py-50 xl:py-100 remove-header">
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-20 xl:-mx-20">
        <div class="w-full xl:px-20">
          <h2 class="leading-none xl:leading-80 mb-30 xl:mb-50 font-title text-4xl xl:text-7xl xxl:text-8xl text-center">
            Some title
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="pt-50 xl:pt-100 pb-15 xl:pb-25 cursor-hover header-hover">
    <div class="xl:px-50 xxl:px-100">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-20 lg:mx-0 xl:-mx-20">
        <div class="w-full mb-30 xl:mb-50 lg:px-20">
          <p>&copy; 2024 test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>




</body>

</html>




Please include relevant HTML/CSS to help demonstrate the issue. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@showdev question updated

There are a few ways to accomplish this design goal. These come to mind:

Watching the scroll event and changing the header styling as you have suggested based upon logic of how the scroll has changed
Using an interval and checking where elements are, changing styles to match where things are at that second
Using an IntersectionObserver to fire off events when elements intersect the desired area, changing styling to reflect which intersecting elements fired off
Use mix-blend-mode: difference without a fixed stacking context
Adjust design to include a background / text shadow for header to maintain readability anywhere

Of these, I believe the IntersectionObserver is the best fit. Not only does it handle some of the logic for you, but it also fires off fewer times so heavy logic will be more performant.
Unfortunately, the code snippet tool has unexpected results using scroll events due to the misreadings of viewport values, however you can view a demo here and I will also post the code of how to accomplish this using scroll and intersection observer in plain text here.
<header>Header of Intersection Demo</header>
<section>section 1</section>
<section>section 2</section>
<section>section 3</section>
<section>section 4</section>
<section>section 5</section>
<section>section 6</section>
<section>section 7</section>

body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font: bold 20pt monospace;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

section {
  height: 80dvh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

The HTML and CSS are the same for the two demos. In my scroll demo, the js behaves as follows:

define a helper function to grab elements from the dom
create a reference to the header to refer to
figure out where the header ends in px value
get a list of light and dark sections
define a helper function to tell whether or not another element has either it's top or bottom border intersecting the header
add a memory of the last scroll position
add an event listener to the scroll event which


determines the current scroll position




use that info to determine if scrolling up or down




use up / down to determine whether we're looking at the top or bottom of elements to intersect the header




check our light elements for intersections




change color if intersecting




do the same for dark



Some limitations to this, it calculates a LOT! This is especially apparent on my site demo where I have it update a counter in the top right every time the scroll event fires.
Additionally, it fails if you scroll too quickly. This is because the scroll event does not fire at an infinite speed. If you scroll faster than it can fire, it will never detect the intersection. You could add some logic to see which element is currently behind the header instead of detecting intersections and that may help, but I still opted for the intersection observer described after my scroll demo code.
// Scroll Demo
const get = query => [...document.querySelectorAll(query)];
 
const header = get("header")[0];
const headerHeight = header.getClientRects()[0].bottom;

const lightSections = get("section:nth-of-type(odd)");
const darkSections = get("section:nth-of-type(even)");

const elementIsIntersectingHeader = (element, topOrBottom) => {
    const elementSidePosition = element.getClientRects()[0][topOrBottom];
    return elementSidePosition < headerHeight && elementSidePosition > 0;
};


let lastScrollPosition = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    const scrollingDown = currentScrollPosition > lastScrollPosition;
    lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;

    const sideOfElementIsIntersectingHeader = scrollingDown ?
        element => elementIsIntersectingHeader(element, "top") :
        element => elementIsIntersectingHeader(element, "bottom");
    const lightSectionIntersects = lightSections.some(sideOfElementIsIntersectingHeader);
    if (lightSectionIntersects) return header.style.color = "black";
    const darkSectionIntersects = darkSections.some(sideOfElementIsIntersectingHeader);
    if (darkSectionIntersects) return header.style.color = "white";
});

Intersection Observers!
A handy browser hook to see when your viewport intersects with an element. Lets break down the code below:

helper function to grab elements from the dom
reference light sections and dark sections for later
reference header for later
calculate the bottom offset (full screen height - header height) so we can know how much to adjust out intersection observation by
create an intersection observer for light elements which


checks if an entry is currently intersecting (they also fire the event when exiting intersection)




If so change the color




add the settings for rootMargin so it fires not when it enters the screen but when it intersects the fixed header


attach the observer to all the light elements
repeat last 5 steps for dark sections

And Viola! Potential draw backs, the color changes when it first intersects, so if you intersect partially then turn back directions, you would not have it change back colors.
// Intersection Demo
const get = query => [...document.querySelectorAll(query)];

const lightSections = get("section:nth-of-type(odd)");
const darkSections = get("section:nth-of-type(even)");

const header = get("header")[0];

const bottomOffset = -1 * window.innerHeight + header.scrollHeight;

const lightObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    const intersectingEntries = entries.filter(entry => entry.isIntersecting);
    if (intersectingEntries.length === 0) return;
    header.style.color = "black";
  },
  {
    rootMargin: `0px 0px ${bottomOffset}px 0px`
  }
);

lightSections.forEach(
  section => lightObserver.observe(section)
);

const darkObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    const intersectingEntries = entries.filter(entry => entry.isIntersecting);
    if (intersectingEntries.length === 0) return;
    header.style.color = "white";
  },
  {
    rootMargin: `0px 0px ${bottomOffset}px 0px`
  }
);

darkSections.forEach(
  section => darkObserver.observe(section)
);

Realistically, I believe you'd use a combination of strategies in production. You might have an interval which checks at a slow rate in case something is missed, with an intersection observer to fire the moment it crosses.
Hopefully this helps! If you need any further clarification, don't hesitate to ask <3
